# Find all functions such that $f(xf(y)+y)=f(xy)+f(y)$

Tags: functions

Find all functions, $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(xf(y)+y)=f(xy)+f(y)$$

What i have got till now is

> Let $$P(x,y): f(xf(y)+y)=f(xy)+f(y)$$Then
> \begin{align*}
> &P(0,0):  f(0)=f(0)+f(0)\implies f(0)=0\\
> &P\Bigg(\frac{y}{y-f(y)},y\Bigg): f(y)=0
> \end{align*}
> Hence $f(x)=0$ is a solution.

But we can see $f(x)=x$ is also a solution but I can't find that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $y$ such that $f(y) \ne y$, replace $(x,y) = (\frac{y}{y-f(y)},y)$ in the equation, we have that $f(y) = 0$. Indeed,
$$f(\frac{y}{y-f(y)}f(y)+y) = f(\frac{y}{y-f(y)}y)+f(y)$$
$$\iff f(\frac{y^2}{y-f(y)}) = f(\frac{y}{y-f(y)}y)+f(y)$$
$$\iff 0 = f(y)$$

So, we have for all $x$, $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) =x$.

**If $\exists y_0 \ne 0$ such that $f(y_0) = 0$**

Then we have, for all $x$
$$f(xf(y_0)+y_0)=f(xy_0)+f(y_0)$$
$$\iff f(x.0+y_0)=f(xy_0)+0$$
$$\iff 0=f(xy_0)$$
Hence, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$: $f(x)=0$

**If $\not\exists y_0 \ne 0$ such that $f(y_0) = 0$**

Then for all $x\ne0$, $f(x) \ne 0$. Because $f(x)$ can only receive value in $\{0,x \}$, then $f(x) = x$ for all $x$

**Conclusion**

There are 2 solutions: $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = x$.